# Access Form1 elements from filesystemeventhandler

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, events, filesystemwatcher

I have a program that is checking for changes in a file, then once the file changes it reads it and updates some labels. "However it crashes because I am trying to change elements in a thread from a different thread" ~ Or so I think. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace RoomAutomation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void readfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Dandrews\control.txt");
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Path = @"C:\Users\Dandrews\";
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;
            fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            if (lines[0] == "1:lights")
            {
                Lights.Text = "Lights are on.";
            }
            if (lines[0] == "0:lights")
            {
                Lights.Text = "Lights are off.";
            }
            if (lines[1] == "1:camera")
            {
            Camera.Text = "Camera is on.";
            }
            if (lines[1] == "0:camera")
            {
                Camera.Text = "Camera is off.";
            }
            if (lines[2] == "1:speakers")
            {
                Speakers.Text = "Speakers are on.";
            }
            if (lines[2] == "0:speakers")
            {
                Speakers.Text = "Speakers are off.";
            }
            if (lines[3] == "1:playlist")
            {
                Playlist.Text = "Playlist is on.";
            }
            if (lines[3] == "0:playlist")
            {
                Playlist.Text = "Playlist is off.";
            }        
        }
        private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {            
            Console.Write("Changes");
            //Lights.Text = "New label Text";

        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What exception are you getting? And *why* did you put quotes around your question?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yeah ive noticed I read the code to quickly therefor removed my comment before I could see you responded to it. :)

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
The program '[6316] RoomAutomation.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Quotes are around what I believe the issue is. :)

Comment: @user1116969 - Please include valid portions of your stack trace in your question. It is almost more important to know *which line* the exception is occurring on.

Answer (score 1):

That's because FileSystemWatcher raises its events on a threadpool thread.  Which is the natural way, those file system events happen asynchronously.  You cannot directly access any UI components in the event handler, they are not thread-safe.  The InvalidOperationException is there to remind you that you can't.

Fixing it takes adding a single line of code:

```
        fsw.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

Which forces FileSystemWatcher to marshal the event handler call to the thread that created the form, the UI thread.  This is not necessarily the best solution, there's a great deal of overhead involved in marshaling the call.  But you'll be quite okay with this solution since you *have* to marshal for each event anyway with the code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 2.0 and up [doesn't allow you to access UI elements from other threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You have to call invoke the code you want to run on the control.  If you're porting.NET 1.1 code, here's a simple hack to make your life easier:

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/11/06/using-anonymous-methods-with-control-invoke/

Comment: Not porting .NET 1.1 code. Looking for an easy workaround using .NET 2.0 and newer.

Comment: That /is/ the easy workaround for .NET 2.0 and newer - I only mention migration because I've had to do that in the past. :-)  The less easy workaround would be to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @user1116969 That /is/ the easy workaround for .NET 2.0 and newer - I only mention migration because I've had to do that in the past. :-)  Whatever code you wanted to call in your FSW's OnChanged event, wrap in an anonymous delegate and pass to your form elements' Invoke method - nice and easy resolution.  Another option would be to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) and implement the ProgressChanged event, but please take a look at what approach works best for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I want the FSW OnChanged event to either re-read the file and change the labels, or to run a readfile.PerformClick();. How would I go about this? Either by wraping some code in a delegate and passing it or some crafty other way of doing it.

Comment: This wasn't allowed in .NET 1.x either.  .NET 2.0 was just the first version to remind you about it.

Comment: It wasn't a good idea, and definately unsafe, but it does build & run - sometimes with hilarious consequences.  This for example: `private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(crossThread);
   Thread booer = new Thread(start);
   booer.Start();
  }
  
  private void crossThread()
  {
   this.textBox1.Text = "boo!";
  }`  As opposed to .NET 2.0+, where the cross-thread access throws an InvalidOperationException.